# writing Hebrew in my website's top menu

Tags: css, html

I bought [this template][1], and I’m customizing it. The only problem I’ve got is that the template’s top menu gets blank when I write in Hebrew. I don’t know why, but I hope you can get me a solution.

The problem is with the home link on the top bar.

Comment: Maybe asking the person you bought the template from would be a good place to get support.

Comment: I don’t see any Hebrew in the link you put up. Could you post a link with the problematic code? If not on your own site, then on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar.

Comment: Isn't linking to the raw files of your purchased Template a violation of your license agreement?

Comment: nahhh, i'm sorry about that was too upset... and about the license agreement thanx for the tip dude :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using cufon to redraw the menu, when I stop hiding your original text i can see the Hebrew.  cufon must be choking on the font for some reason.